# How to use factory Angular with interface?

Tags: angular

Here is an interface:

```
interface Service {
  make(): void;
  get(): any;
}
```

And two services that implement this contract:

```
class Service1 implements Service {
   constructor(private rootService: RootService) {}
   make() {}
   get() {}
}


class Service2 implements Service {
   constructor(private rootService: RootService) {}
   make() {}
   get() {}
}
```

I need to use the concrete implementation of service in component A and component B with the same name but with the different implementation:

```
class Component A {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}

class Component B {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}
```

How to do that considering the service has dependency: `private rootService: RootService`?

Comment: The thing with this approach is about the scope. How are Service1 and Service2 provided? Are they stateful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you could just provide different implementations for the `Service` interface at the component level (assuming that Service1 and Service2 are stateless).

To circumvent the fact that the interface cannot be used as an injection token, you can create a new injection token for this purpose:

```js
export const MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<Service>('MY_SERVICE');
```

```js
@Component({
  // ...,
  providers: [{
    provide: MY_SERVICE,
    useClass: Service1
  }]
})
class Component A {
  constructor(@Inject(MY_SERVICE) private service: Service) {}
}
// ...
@Component({
  // ...,
  providers: [{
    provide: MY_SERVICE,
    useClass: Service2
  }]
})
class Component B {
  constructor(@Inject(MY_SERVICE) private service: Service) {}
}
```

Comment: This will not work. `Service` is only interface, but only class can be provided and injected. `Service` needs to be declared as `abstract class`.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis Please check the updated answer.