# Angular injector.get of abstract class

Tags: javascript, angular, provider, inject

In my angular project I've got many components: each one of the has a provider. The provider is a custom service which extends an abstract class.
Each one of these components can open a dialog (opened with MatDialog), and I would like to get the component's provider with injector.get, but how can I do that with an abstract class?
Example:

```
@Component({
  providers: [FirstClass] // this extends BaseClass
})
export class MyComponent{}

@Component({
  providers: [SecondClass] // this extends BaseClass
})
export class SecondComponent{}
```

From the dialog I would like to do something like this:

```
injector.get<BaseClass>(BaseClass)
```

But I noticed that this isn't possible, so is there another way to take their provider having that abstract class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have a possibility to do it by using injection token instead. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73700910/1440005) for inspiration. Then you can use `injector.get<BaseClass>(MY_TOKEN)`

Answer (score 0):

in your case `BaseClass` token is used to inject an instance. thus you need to register something with this token

```
providers: [{
  provide: BaseClass,
  useClass: SecondClass
}]
```

or, you could make your class injectable by several tokens

```
providers: [
 SecondClass,
 {
   provide: BaseClass,
   useExisting: SecondClass
  }
]
```

in 2nd version you could inject Second class with both `BaseClass` and `SecondClass` token

Comment: But I can't do it at this point, since this is a refactoring, and I would need to edit like 200 files..

Comment: you can declare these providers at any level. so if your component A does this thing - all of the components in its subtree would inject SecondClass with the help of BaseClass token

Comment: @Luse I thought a bit and you could try to patch the Injector class' prototype to search also by superclass of your required service